# Map<Integer, List<courseCLS>> to Map<Integer, List<Course>>

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have an `interface Course` and a `class CourseCLS implements Course` .

First I tried to group `CourseCLS` objects by the same numbers. I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

```
Map<Integer, List<CourseCLS>> first =
        courses.values().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getNumber()));
```

Now I need to change `Map<Integer, List<CourseCLS>>` into `Map<Integer, List<Course>>`, and then return it.

Any ideas how to do it?

#### Just solved adding this to groupingBy:

```
groupingBy(c -> c.overHeadPercentage(),
    Collectors.mapping(p -> (Course) p, Collectors.toList()))
```

Comment: You can just cast it (though you'll get a warning). But why not declare `first` as the type you need to return? Does `Course` not have `getNumber()`? Are you doing something else with the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to solve a problem which doesn’t exist. Just write

```
Map<Integer, List<Course>> first =
    courses.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getNumber()));
```

Since the Stream elements are instances of `CourseCLS` which implements `Course`, you can collect them into a `List<Course>` without the need for any additional action.

---

The only possible problem could arise, if the `Course` interface doesn’t have the `getNumber` method, but only the concrete `CourseCLS` class, as the collector above is now collecting `Course` instances. But even this can be solved without any mapping step:

```
Map<Integer, List<Course>> first =
    courses.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.getNumber(), Collectors.toList()));
```

Since `groupingBy` allows the downstream collector to collect a broader type than itself collects, you can combine a `toList()` collector collecting `Course` instances with a `groupingBy` collector which collects `CourseCLS` instances. The type inference of `Java 8` detects the validity of this construct.

Answer (score 1):

Since CourseCLS implements Course you can just make a new Map with Course as value, it will accept any instance of Course interface so will accept CourseCLS.
So go though your first map and add every K,V pair to the result Map

Comment: Can you write code exactly? I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Having you `Map<Integer, List<CourseCLS>> first` done, just do this: `Map<Integer, List<Course>> second = new HashMap(); first.forEach(second::putIfAbsent);` This will add every K,V of first into the second with no key replace.